# Frequency of alphabets repeated are not calculated properly

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I am trying to read a frequency from a file to create huffman tree. I am able to do that but there is a problem. The problem is this that i am using two `for() loops i and j` and at the place where the alphabet repeats at that place it shows "0". I mean suppose the alphabet is `"aababccc"` the output is this:

```
a=3,a=0,b=2,a=0,b=0,c=3,c=0,c=0
```

but I want the output to be like this:

```
a=3, b=2,c=3
```

I mean i have to remove these zero from memory allocation i have done (i am storing them in  sym[] and freq[]).Please help me in doing that (any language c or c++)

```
    int flag[256];
    int j = 0;
    char sym[256];
    int freq[256];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        flag[i] = {0};
    int fcount1 = 0;
    sym[i] = data[i].symbol;
    freq[i] = fcount1;
        fcount1 = 0;
    }

}
```

The input frequency given to it are : **abaabbcacaeeded** which are stored in **data[index].symbol**
And the output corresponding to it is:

**Everything is correct except these "0". Please help me in removing these "0".**

Comment: This is an incomplete code right? there is something above this code too.. am i right?

Comment: @DakshShah here is the full code .Thanks for the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before the `j` loop, add a condition:

```
if (flag[i] == 0)
```

Also, build the `storesym` and `storefreq` arrays dynamically using vectors and push_back

```
int flag[256];//this flag is to know if the alphabet is already counted or not.If counted that i set it to "1" other wise it is "0".Please see below in my code
int j = 0,i;
std::vector<char> storesym;
std::vector<int> storefreq;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  flag[i] = {0};
int fcount1 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    if (flag[i] == 0)
    {
        for (j = i; j < count; j++) 
        {
           if (data[i].symbol == data[j].symbol && flag[j] == 0) 
           {
              fcount1++;
              flag[j] = 1;//**I am setting flag to 1 those alphabets to 1 so that they will not be counted again on next iteration**
           }
        }
        storesym.push_back( data[i].symbol );
        storefreq.push_back( fcount1 );
    }
    fcount1 = 0;
}
cout << endl;
for (i = 0; i < storesym.size(); i++) 
{
    cout << "storesym[i] :" << storesym[i] << endl;//it stores the symbol. 
    cout << "storefreq[i] :" << storefreq[i] << endl;//it stores the frequency.
}
```

Comment: How to do std::vector<char> storesym;
std::vector<int> storefreq; in c ?

Comment: @user234839 you are using C++ headers (iostream and fstream) and not C. You will have to #include <vector> as well.

Comment: thanks for the help, let me try it, if succeds i will vote you up.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: yup -- I just removed the "C" tag.

Comment: @Abhishek you code is working properly but I still have one doubt and i want to clear it with you. I tried something like inside the "j" for loop(inner loop):  if(flag[j]==1){j=j+1;} but it didn't work, My logic was if i have if (data[i].symbol == data[j].symbol && flag[j] == 0){then this code executes} and if if(flag[j]==1){j=j+1;} //it will shift by one index until i don't have character equal to flag[j]=0, but it didn't work. Could you please explain why it didn't worked?

Comment: @user234839 The logic is that if you have already counted the particular 'data[i]', then you should not check it further. Otherwise its count will be zero (because all the corresponding j's shall be flagged already) and you would add it to your list unnecessarily. Your modified code didn't work because it did not change anything. You are already checking for flag[j] == 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it is 0 or not, if it is '0' don't store it